# run bat file at startup

Tags: windows-server-2008, batch-file

How do I run a bat file at startup in Windows 2008?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Windows Scheduler -- When my computer starts**

I'm pretty sure you can the built-in Windows Scheduler to execute your batch file on startup.

Try this:

Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks

Select the location of your batch file and on the next page select "When my computer starts".

You may also want to move it to somewhere OTHER than the startup folder to avoid "weirdness".

Good luck!

Comment: If the computer is a member server in a domain you can also do this through Group Policy, but I am assuming you would have said that if it were true.

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions and I am going to assume still in Windows 2008 you can set a scheduled task to be run "when the computer starts" instead of at a specific time.

Update:
Just checked a test Windows 2008 machine of mine.

Run Task Scheduler from the start menu search box.
Choose Create Basic Task on the right.
On the trigger selection, you will have choices for "When the computer starts" and "When I log on"

Answer (score 0):

Place the batch file into the 'Startup' folder for the user. Or do you want to run it before the user signs in?

Answer (score 0):

Fire up an mmc, add it local computer policy settings snap-in and in Windows settings/Scripts put your startup script.

Answer (score 0):

Run a batch file at loading of `Windows 8 and 10 and windows server 2016`.

1. Create a shortcut to the batch file.
2. Once the shortcut is created, 'right-click' the shortcut file and select Cut.
3. Press `Start` on the keyboard, type `Run`, and press Enter.
4. In the Run window, type `shell:startup` to open the Startup folder.
5. Once the Startup folder is opened, click the `Home` tab at the top of the folder. Then, select `Paste` to paste the shortcut file into the Startup folder.

I hope is useful.